# Writing theorem conditions with automatic numbering and labels

Tags: cross-referencing, amsthm, newtheorem

I'm trying to write conditions that are required for a theorem to be valid such that the condition is automatically numbered AND is able to be referenced at a later time (e.g. a link can be used to go back to the initial condition definition.)

The format I am trying to obtain is:

```
(C1) Statement about the required process
```

And the in document reference would be:

```
Following from (C1), we have that blah.
```

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{amsthm}

% Define new theorem environment that works only with conditions
\newtheorem{Condition}{C}


\crefname{Condition}{C}{C} % singular and plural forms of label


\begin{document}

% Attempt 1
\begin{Condition}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Statement about the required process. \label{cond:test}
\item Next statement about the required process. \label{cond:test2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Condition}

% Attempt 2
\begin{Condition}
Statement about the required process. \label{cond:test3}
\end{Condition}

(C\ref{cond:test}, \ref{cond:test2}, \ref{cond:test3}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your 'reference' system is not yet well-designed

Comment: Using `\Cref` for `cond:test` or `cond:test2` it will print `Item` because that's the counter connected to the label, not `Condition`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible way, to use the items of `enumerate` and make them a `subcondition`, using the `Condition` counter as a parent.

'Itemless' conditions should use a similar reference label, being printed as `(C2)` etc. In order to achieve this, one has to change the `\p@Condition` macro, in order to grab the counter name first and append the `)` afterwards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}


\newtheorem{Condition}{C}



\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}



\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin={40pt},label=(C\theCondition.\arabic*),ref=(C\theCondition.\arabic*),before={\leavevmode}}

\makeatletter
\def\@grabconditioncounter\csname #1\endcsname{%
  (C\csname#1\endcsname)%
}

\renewcommand\p@Condition{\@grabconditioncounter}

\makeatother



\begin{document}


\begin{Condition}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Statement about the required process. \label{cond:test}

\item Next statement about the required process. \label{cond:test2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Condition}

% Attempt 2
\begin{Condition}
Statement about the required process. \label{cond:test3}
\end{Condition}


Following from \ref{cond:test}, we have that\dots, but \ref{cond:test2} and \ref{cond:test3} are important also. 


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** A version with (C1) numbering as 'theorem' head with an environment.

I've put the `\setlist` changes of enumerate inside of the `Condition` environment such that other usages of `enumerate` will not have the 'strange' enumeration labels then.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{Condition}
\newenvironment{Condition}{%
\setlist[enumerate,1]{font={\itshape},leftmargin={40pt},label=(C\theCondition.\arabic*),ref=(C\theCondition.\arabic*)}%,before={\leavevmode}}
\parindent=0em
  \refstepcounter{Condition}%
  \textbf{(C\theCondition)} 

  %Explicit newline above
}{%
}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\def\@grabconditioncounter\csname #1\endcsname{%
  (C\csname#1\endcsname)%
}
\renewcommand\p@Condition{\@grabconditioncounter}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{Condition}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Statement about the required process. \label{cond:test}

\item Next statement about the required process. \label{cond:test2}
\end{enumerate}
\end{Condition}

% Attempt 2
\begin{Condition}
Statement about the required process. \label{cond:test3}
\end{Condition}


Following from \ref{cond:test}, we have that\dots, but \ref{cond:test2} and \ref{cond:test3} are important also. 

\begin{enumerate}
\item A 
\item B
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks. I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: @coatless: You're welcome. Nevertheless, I think you should think about the precise numbering in future documents

Comment: Could you clarify "Precise numbering?" Also, is there an easy way to get the definition label updated to `(C1)` vs. the present `C 1`?

Comment: @coatless: The precise numbering means how sub conditions are numbered (your `\item`s, for example). The (C1) is more difficult since you're using a theorem (unnecessarily, in my point of view, a normal environment would be easier to change)

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I think I might be able to get the `(C1)` aspect by switching the `theoremstyle` definition. I'll report back later. Thank you again for your concise and on point answer!

Comment: @coatless: `\newtheoremstyle` is a possible option. I've added a non-theorem approach

Comment: the item "numbers" would really be much nicer upright.  `\textup` can be applied to do that, although i'm not where i can experiment; `amsthm` does set these labels upright by default, but something in these particular definitions seems to be overriding that setting.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks for commenting, but as usual I leave the real typesetting and choice of font shape etc. to the O.P.