# Remove trailing period from captions in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, listings, tocloft

Every figure, table, formula and listing in my document has a caption that ends with a period. The problem is, that these periods are also displayed in the ToC, which they shouldn't.

I found a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366351/period-in-toc-but-not-in-reference) which had the goal of removing trailing periods from the section numbers by preventing them from getting written to the `.aux` file:

```
\makeatletter
\def\remove@@dot\csname the#1\endcsname{\Roman{#1}}
\def\p@section{\remove@@dot}
\makeatother
```

However, I haven't figured out a way to do the same for the captions themselves - that being said, I am pretty new to LaTeX. Of course it would be possible to provide a second argument without the period to the `\caption` command to specify a *short* spelling, that is used for the ToC, like this: `\caption[Some caption]{Some caption.}`, but these are redundancies I'd rather avoid.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{listings}


%% Setup for list of equations
%% ========================================
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{Equations}
\newlistof{equations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\eqcaption}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{equ}{equations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par%
}


%% Actual document
%% ========================================
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofequations
\lstlistoflistings

%% Example elements with captions ending in a period
\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Some figure.}
\end{figure}\noindent

\begin{table}[h]
    \caption{Some table.}
\end{table}

\begin{equation}
\end{equation}\eqcaption{Some equation.}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Some code.}]
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution that works, but definitely isn't perfect.

For figures and tables I override the default `\caption` command to gobble the trailing period, if present, but only for the ToC entry.

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\Caption\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[2][]{%
    \ifstrempty{#1}{%
        \IfEndWith{#2}{.}{%
            \StrGobbleRight{#2}{1}[\result]%
            \Caption[\result]{#2}%
        }{%
            \Caption[#2]{#2.}%
        }%
    }{\Caption[#1]{#2}}%
}
```

The same goes for the equation captions, with the only difference being that the command is already custom, so that wasn't a problem.

```
\newcommand{\eqcaption}[1]{%
    \IfEndWith{#1}{.}{%
        \StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\result]%
        \addcontentsline{equ}{equations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}\result}%
    }{%
        \addcontentsline{equ}{equations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}%
    }\par%
}
```

Finally for the listings I tried to patch the underlying TeX macro via `xpatch` but couldn't get it to work, so instead I added a new command that defines two values which I use for the caption parameter - one with the period and the other one without it.

```
\newcommand{\lstcaption}[1]
    {\IfEndWith{#1}{.}{%
        \StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\result]%
        \def\lsttoccap{\result}%
        \def\lstcap{#1}}
    {\def\lsttoccap{#1}%
        \def\lstcap{#1.}}}

\lstcaption{Some code}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={[\lsttoccap]\lstcap}]
\end{lstlisting}
```

I also added the functionality that a period will automatically be appended to the caption, if it wasn't explicitly specified.